# get text between two dfferent tags using JSOUP in grails from XHTML document

Tags: html, grails, tags, xhtml, jsoup

I am trying to get all the text of a tag `ae_definedtermtitlebegin` within my xhtml document. This tags occurs 1000 times in the entire document. I am trying to create a list of the text associated with this tag. I am using JSOUP and grails. The code  have written so far

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file,"UTF-8")
Elements pres = doc.getElementsByTag("ae_definedTermTitleBegin");
println pres //This prints a list which contains the tag itself fr eg. [<ae_definedtermtitlebegin/>,<ae_definedtermtitlebegin/>,<ae_definedtermtitlebegin/>....]
for (Element pre : pres) {
    println pre.text() //prints nothing. I assumed this would print the text within the tag
}
```

Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it. 
In the xhtml document the text would look like

```
<ae_definedTermTitleBegin />Applicable Permitted Investment
Amount<ae_definedTermTitleEnd />
```

**I jsut realised my content is between two different tags. How do I fetch the text between this two tags ?**

Comment: I came across with other solution using SAX Parser. Thanks for your help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302758/discard-html-tags-within-custom-tags-while-getting-text-in-xhtml-using-sax-parse

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    /*  String html =   "<ae_definedTermTitleBegin />" +
                            "Applicable Permitted Investment Amount" +
                        "<ae_definedTermTitleEnd />";
    */
        String html = "<ae_definedTermTitleBegin />" +
                        "Applicable Permitted Investment Amount" +
                        "<ae_definedTermTitleBegin />" +
                            "Inner example" +
                        "<ae_definedTermTitleEnd />" +
                        "This is harder" +
                       "<ae_definedTermTitleEnd />";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        List<TextNode> lines = getTextBetweenTags(doc.getElementsByTag("body").get(0).childNodes(), 
                                                    "ae_definedTermTitleBegin", "ae_definedTermTitleEnd");

        System.out.println(lines);
    }

    private static List<TextNode> getTextBetweenTags(List<Node> listOfNodes, String tagStart, String tagEnd) {

        List<TextNode> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        int inRangeCounter = 0;
        for(Node node : listOfNodes) {
            if(node.nodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagStart)) {
                inRangeCounter++;
            } else if(node.nodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagEnd)) {
                inRangeCounter--;
            } else if(inRangeCounter > 0 && node instanceof TextNode) {
                lines.add((TextNode)node);
            }
        }

        return lines;
    }
}
```